# Showing percentage without decimal using billboardjs on pie chart

Tags: javascript

I am using billboardjs to draw a pie chart .
When pie chart displayed it's shows percentage as `60.0%` and  `40.0%` like that.
I want to display it as `60%` and `40%` . I don't want to display decimal part .
Any help .

Comment: Please show us what you tried

Answer (score 1):

You can use `toFixed(x)` function that allows you to chose the number of decimal after the comma

Source : https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_tofixed.asp

For example : `(42.4).toFixed(0) === 42`

Comment: I will try this... basically I wanted to check how can we do in billboard js piechart .how to override the percentage value in billboardjs